# MySQL: Where this is true, if not, then this

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ranks
WHERE
    (price = 25.00 AND accumulate = 0)
    OR
    (price <= (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM donations WHERE username = 'username' AND amount IN (SELECT price FROM ranks WHERE accumulate = 1)))
ORDER BY price
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Basically I want to return the first where clause if it finds a match, otherwise return the second clause.

Comment: It does not work that way. It returns any records that satisfy either one of the condition in the OR clause.

Comment: Then how can I achieve my desired result with only one query?...

Comment: do you have records with price = 25.00 and accumulate = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will work

```
SELECT *
FROM ranks
WHERE price = 25.00 AND accumulate = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM ranks
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                  FROM ranks
                  WHERE price = 25.00 AND accumulate = 0)
      AND (price <= (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM donations WHERE username = 'username' AND        amount IN (SELECT price FROM ranks WHERE accumulate = 1)))
ORDER BY price
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @BrianGraham Cool... But Check whether this executes faster as it uses `UNION`

Comment: This query is only ran when paypal connects to my IPN file, so speed isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query with IF

```
SELECT *
FROM ranks
WHERE if(price = 25.00,accumulate = 0, price <= (SELECT
                           SUM(amount)
                         FROM donations
                         WHERE username = 'username'
                             AND amount IN(SELECT
                                     price
                                   FROM ranks
                                   WHERE accumulate = 1)))
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Nope, I get the same result as the original. Only the `price <= ...` result is ever returned.